# Where does python get the value for path when running Django/WSGI

Tags: django, django-wsgi

In brief:

**views.py:**

```
def display_path(request):
    import os
    return HttpResponse("The path is %s" % os.path.abspath("."))
```

Results in

> The path is /var/www

Is it possible to change that value, or is it set by httpd/WSGI?

Comment: I think it has something about httpd config! because i just did that test in my 2 environments and both returned "The path is /"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never rely on the current working directory being a specific location in web applications because what it will be will be different for different hosting mechanisms. So, don't even try to change the current working directory as it will only lead to grief eventually by then relying on that.

Instead you should organise your code to use an absolute path. This would need to be either hard coded, be added as a suffix to some prefix from configuration, or calculated on the fly relative to the location of the code file being executed. In the latter you would do:

```
import os
here = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = os.path.join(here, 'relative/path/file.txt')
```

Comment: The problem was I was using django-mailer (http://code.google.com/p/django-mailer/) which assumes that a certain command will **always** be run from the command line. When it isn't, it tries to create a thread file at `/var/www/...` which predictably fails (and no, I'm not giving apache write access to `/var/www`). My fix was to alter the code for django-mailer so that you can manually set the path for the thread file.